# How to automate strafe jumping?

Tags: c++, game-mechanics, automation

I'm a complete noob when it comes to math so excuse my ignorance. I've trying to automate strafe jumping (from the quake engine) into another quake engine based game. I've tried a fair bit to get this to work but I can't wrap my head around the math and what I'm supposed to do with it.

[This link here](https://dimit.me/blog/2017/08/08/defrag-strafe-theory/) perfectly describes how to strafe jump & the mechanics involved. I have a lot of the calculations from it implemented, but I don't know how to go about automating the strafe jumping.

Would it possible for someone to show some pseudocode on how to implement an automated way to achieve this? I basically need the player to automatically strafe at the most optimal angle from only pressing W + A or W + D.

Thanks!

Comment: As a veteran Quake 3 trick jumper, I'm pretty sure this can't be easily automated since it would have to rotate your player a different amount depending on your speed, and that's going to feel HORRIBLE as a player. Also sometimes you want to keep strafing, but not keep accelerating, as you might need to land right on an edge for a perfect jump.

Comment: As a general rule, I've found that when a question requires visiting an external link to understand, that question will be slow to attract answers. The more off-site reading/watching required, the lower the response rate. Asking a volunteer to pour over 11 printed pages worth of explanations and diagrams before they can understand concretely what you want help with is basically a recipe to guarantee you never get answers.  To combat this, try to distill the math you want help with into a concise statement you can fit into the body of the question itself, using images or MathJax to clarify.